# Python JSON encoding Verification

Tags: python, json

I am trying to scan in a text document that  I have and then find certain sections and output it to a file in json format.

Unfortunatly I am not to sure how to use json and would appricate it if someone could tell me how to encode it as json properly.

Thank you everyone!

```
    #save word and type to database 
    word = [{'WORD':strWrd , 'TYPE':strWrdtyp}]

    with open(input_lang+'.dic', 'a') as outfile:
            try:
                json.dump(word, outfile)
                outfile.write('\n')
                outfile.close
            except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:
                print 'Error:', err
```

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but I think your code is correct. Are you having a problem with it? If so, what is the problem?

Comment: Hello Barmar, I am not sure if I am saving it correct and if I am saving it correct how do I read it back in? After I make the file with the data in it, I was to go through the file and check all of the "TYPE" values and make a list of them. I am not sure how to refer to these values

Comment: You just need to `import json`. To read it back just `for line in open('file.dic'): json.loads(line)`.

Comment: You read it back in with `json.load()`. It's all explained in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: So I have to read it back line by line? Is there no way to just read the document as a whole?

Comment: Why not use the string data currently in memory? Why write to disk and read it right back in?